# Powershell Get-WebVirtualDirectory : Specified cast is not valid

Tags: casting, powershell-3.0

I've narrowed my code down to this-

```
Function Check-VirtualPhysicalPath{
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [AllowEmptyString()][String]$Page)

 #This creates an arraylist of items that are our virtual/physical paths
 $WebVD= Get-WebVirtualDirectory
}
```

when I run this script in a function setting the results of 'Get-WebVirtualDirectory' returns a casting error. This has me baffled because when i try to run the line

```
   $WebVD= Get-WebVirtualDirectory
```

in either a script or merely on the console there are no errors returned and i can access the variable and the data is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Now as a side-note this is merely the problematic code so i'm not including everything, but even when i comment everything else out i end up just running what you see here with problems just the same.

i'm calling the code with this in a separate script

```
$page = [string]$(gc "C:\page.txt")

. C:\VP.ps1

$(Check-VirtualPhysicalPath($page))
```

Powershell is reacting like i'm casting the $WebVD variable, I'm not sure if this is a bug or if i'm missing something entirely...

**Edit:**

it looks like i forgot to pull out that part of the code.  I'm code crawling, the point of the hashtable is that i'm storing the number of times a resource is used in a hash table with the key being the file name and the value how many times it has been used so i use regular expressions to determine that.  My question is unrelated to my other code because it's having problems even when my code only contains what you see above.

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand in your code. What's the use for the $Page variable in the function? Why do you return a hashtable that doesn't seem to be used anywhere? The code you have removed might help use to understand what's happening...

Comment: @DavidBrabant even with only the lines you see above in my code i still get the same error, so it makes more sense to post what i have...